# Java RegEx match if not surrounded by #{.* and .*}

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace all instances of the word **true** in a string,
like for instance in `"true && 0 || 1"`.

It is possible for these strings to contain variable values, marked as `#{varname}`.
I don't want to replace the instances which are surrounded by `#{` and `}`.

Example:
`"true && #{ab_true_cd} || 0"`
should be converted to
`"1 && #{ab_true_cd} || 0"`

I tried using this RegEx:
`(?<!\#\{[^\}]*)true`

By using above RegEx I got following error:
Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 13

Do you know a solution or a better approach for this? Or is there a better way than using RegEx?

I used http://regexe.com to test the expressions.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for you to define the instances you don't want to replace as "where `true` is not a word on its own"? I mean, replace all `true` when it stands alone, but not when it's in the middle/start/end of a word.

Comment: You're looking for [this](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).

Comment: Look-behind always should have defined maximum lenght. You cannot use `*`, because it has an infinity potential lenght. You can go around using `{,80}` (or other number that is 100% bigger than your potential string), bat it is not good. In your case you can use `\btrue\b` (`\b` is start or end of the world)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. The best solution for my problem was mentioned by Lucas Trzesniewski and stribizhev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 solutions with regex (both mentioned in the comments by [Lucas Trzesniewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3764814/lucas-trzesniewski) and [TEXHIK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3913440/texhik)):

- **A constrained-width lookbehind solution** (Java regex engine supports lookbehinds that have limiting quantifiers inside):

Java code:

```
String rx = "(?<!#\\{[^{}]{0,500})\\btrue\\b";
String str = "true && #{ab_true_cd} || 0";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(rx, "1"));
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/tUZxJh) (output: `1 && #{ab_true_cd} || 0`)

The regex `(?<!#\\{[^{}]{0,500})\\btrue\\b` matches any whole word `true` that is not preceded with `#{` followed by 0 or up to 500 characters other than `{` or `}`.

- **Another solution** is based on the method of matching what you want to replace and matching *and capturing* what you want to keep.

Code:

```
String s = "true && #{ab_true_cd} || 0";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(#\\{[^{}]*})|\\btrue\\b").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(1)); // if a #{} block found, restore it
    }
    else {
        m.appendReplacement(result, "1"); // else, replace true with 1
    }
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/V9gN9J)

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: https://github.com/update4j/update4j/blob/7c85415aa9c0eaddc007a5febb09089f89d63c2f/src/main/java/org/update4j/util/PropertyManager.java#L244

Comment: @Mordechai In Java 9, there is another nice way to do that using `replaceAll`, but requires the use of `Pattern.compile` and `Matcher` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can split by '&&' or '||', compare each part with word 'true', replace with '1', then merge them again